# How to show image center of the div in css

Tags: css

Trying to show the image center of the div using text-align: center; But not working. Also i have tried using

> display: flex; justify-content: center;

But not working. How to resolve this issue?

app.component.html:

```
    <div class="box">
    <div class="grid1">
    <div class="grid2">
      <img src="https://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/585e4d1ccb11b227491c339b.png" height="24" width="24"/>
    </div>
    <div class="grid3">Content</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

app.component.css:

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 13px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 25px;
}

.grid1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 97.5px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.grid2 {
  margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 7px;
  width: 23.4px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 62px;
  /* display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center; */
}

.grid3 {
  margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 62px;
  font-size: 7px;
  min-width: 64.35px;
  float: left;
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uy4bgp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Your demo is too small...

Comment: To center with Flexbox, you need `justify-content: center;
align-items: center;`.

Comment: @ralph.m: Not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yn3svp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: You need `display: flex` as well. (Sorry, I took it for granted that you'd realize that.)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.img {
  width: 300px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img class="img" src="https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/424/814/HD-wallpaper-nature-nature.jpg" alt="nature images">
</div>
```

use flex, the image will show centering both horizontally and vertically. please try this